# How to stop on Enter Frame firing multiple times?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to do a simple url requestion on enter frame, but it seems to be executing multiple times?

I tried removing the event handler on handleLoadSuccessful, that seems to stop it firing infinitely, but its still executing about 10 times before it stops.

How do I make it only fire once?

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onLoadHandler);
function onLoadHandler(event:Event) {
    var scriptRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://ad.doubleclick.net/clk;254580535;19110122;t?http://www.gamespot.com.au/Ads/gswide/hp/1x1.gif");
    var scriptLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    var scriptVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

    scriptLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleLoadSuccessful);
    scriptLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, handleLoadError);

    scriptRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    scriptRequest.data = scriptVars;

    scriptLoader.load(scriptRequest);

    function handleLoadSuccessful($evt:Event):void {
        trace("Message2 sent.");
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onLoadHandler);

    }

    function handleLoadError($evt:IOErrorEvent):void {
        trace("Message1 failed.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Uhhh..... You realise that ENTER_FRAME is meant to be called *every frame* right? I think you're after a different event.

Comment: @MartyWallace Really?! Thanks that explains, well, everything.

Comment: Yup, `ENTER_FRAME` is generally used to run code every frame like updating all the objects in a game.

Answer (score 0):

`ENTER_FRAME` is fired `x` times per second, where `x` is the document frame rate.

The code within your listening function leads me to thinking that you don't actually need the event listener or the listening function at all - if you just want what's within that function called a single time, move everything within it outside on its own.

You could also move it all into an `init()` function and then call that once.

Also, your functions `handleLoadSuccessful()` and `handleLoadError()` should not be defined within another function (in your case `onLoadHandler()`).